# mysqldump usage with --extended-insert option

Tags: mysql

Is there any specific range for the --extended-insert option of mysqldump that it groups 1024 statements and then uses another extended insert..

My table has more than 10 million rows while dumping the data i haven't changed the max allowed packet size ( it is set to 100 MB ) and my table size is more than 10 GB

Answer (score 3):

If you want group 1024 insert statements, first get the length of a statement. For example, the legnth is 50 characters, total length will be 50K. In this case, try

```
$ mysqldump --net_buffer_length=50K [and your other arguments]
```

As Andreas pointed out you should set `net_buffer_length` and watch `max_allowed_packet`. `mysqldump` with `net_buffer_length = 50K` creates extended insert statements up to 50K long. 4K is the minimum value of `net_buffer_length`. You can also put the option in

```
my.cnf

[mysqldump]
net_buffer_length = 50K
```

Your Mysql server system must have the value larger then what you set for the client. `my.cnf` `[mysqld]` `net_buffer_length = 1M` for example. It's maximum value is `1M`.

`max_allowed_packet` has to be much larger than this. This is packet size for a single statement your client/server will communicate. `max_allowed_packet`'s default value is `16M` and it can be up to `1G` for MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`--net_buffer_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) and/or [`--max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet). They are general client settings but they controls how large each package is even for mysqldump.

Comment: when should i consider increasing max_allowed_packet

Comment: I don't know of any downsides of setting it to max but I'm sure it can't be perfect cause then it would be the default. In your case set it high enough to get a good performance in your dump/load but make sure the settings on the both machines match.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's little bit obsolate, but if someone get stuck again this is what will help him. The problem in here is that mysql engine after executing mysqldump command will buffer all the tables in RAM, and after this is done will write to disk. When the tables cache is greater then size of server RAM we will have a problem. To bridge that use ***--quick*** option (example: *mysqldump -h sitename.com -u root -ppass_word -x --all-databases --quick > dump_file_name.sql*), it will write direct to disk. Besides the option name, this option is not quicker than **BU** with buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, 1.1gb database exported with `--opt` but with lots of records and veeery slow to import, I leaved overnight and next morning it was still importing so I decided to stop and start again.

Found out that this helped a lot https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

I entered the mysql shell and ran:

```
mysql> SET autocommit=0;
mysql> SET unique_checks=0;
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks=0;
mysql> SOURCE my_database.sql;
```

and started to see:

```
Query OK, 12315 rows affected (0.34 sec)
Records: 12315  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

etc.. basically ran around 36k inserts per second but it did got slower overtime..

```
Query OK, 12305 rows affected (1.68 sec)
Records: 12305  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The explanation is simple, autocommit essentially flushes to disk on every insert, even with `--extended-insert` (by default on with `--opt`) but disabling that will group as much as it can before committing to disk, so I was able to group about 12k records before flushing, the other options disabled the key checks for improved performance.

At that rate I was able to import 13 million records in half hour or maybe even less, I didn't checked :)